# Django Serializer getting attribute from another model

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am working just for my experience and I stacked with the following problem. There are three models: `Book`, `Chapter`, and `Publisher`. Each model is related to one another with the foreign key.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
```

I want to serialize the data in `PublisherDetailSerializer` which should show their books and all chapters related to their books.

Here are my serializers:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'publisher')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        return ret

class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    location = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'location')

    def get_location(self, instance):
        serializer = BookSerializer(instance.author, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data

class PublisherSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    books = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'books')

class PublisherDetailSerializer(PublisherSerializer):
    chapters = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'books', 'chapters')

    def get_chapters(self, instance):
        serializer = ChapterSerializer(Chapter.objects.filter(location=instance.books.name), many=True, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        return ret
```

Here is my view for Publisher:

```
class PublisherViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSetMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Publisher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublisherSerializer

    serializer_action_classes = {
        'list': PublisherSerializer,
        'retrieve': PublisherDetailSerializer,
    }
```

Showing publishers and their books shows the right information in the browsable API, but I don't know how to get chapters through books. How should I approach it?

Comment: Have you read the [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

- the `related_name` in a `models.ForeignKey` is not what you thing it is. it is the attribute name to be used on the otherside of the relationship, see the below code
- you can just nest the serializers as shown below

**Models**

```py
class Publisher(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='chapters', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializers**

```py
class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chapters = ChapterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'chapters')

class PublisherSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    books = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'books')
```